# Getting the namespace name from JMS message

Tags: java, jaxb, apache-camel, dozer

I'm using Apache camel JMS, jaxb and dozer mapping.
I need an approach to get the namespace attribute name

For instance

```
<webrequest xmlns:service = "http:xxx/yyy/">
```

...

Need to grab the term service from this JMS message. Suggestions please.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your question is very unclear (for example in what context you need to get the namespace value with what technology), you should check out the [How-to](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) about asking questions.

However, I give it a try to answer without any details. In general you can select the value with XPath

**XPath 2.0**

```
/webrequest/namespace-uri-for-prefix('service',.)
```

**XPath 1.0**

```
/webrequest/namespace::service
```